# MATLAB embed figure window into the editor as a tab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to prevent the MATLAB from creating a separate figure window, and instead show it as a tab in the editor, like the command window or workspace / variables tabs? I'd like to see the figure on the side while still writing on the full-size window. I looked into the settings and couldn't find anything related.

Comment: You can set the location of the figure when you create it. Check the docs for `figure()`

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes but it wouldn't remain on-top when I switched to the editor. As far as I know, I can only make one figure on top of the others, not on top of the editor.

Comment: you can embed the figures into the editor, not sure if that helps

Comment: @AnderBiguri You mean into the text? If so, that's not what I am looking for. If you mean as a tab, then that's the very question. In that case, how?

Comment: programatically: I don't know. But the GUI has a button to dock the figure into the editor. Tiny arrow top right

Comment: @AnderBiguri, yes I was looking for exactly that. Somehow missed it for a loong time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it **programmatically**, just set the figure's [`'WindowStyle'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html) property to `'Docked'`. You can do that when you create the figure:

```
f = figure('WindowStyle', 'Docked');
```